# Is it correct that only transitive verbs can have passive form?

Tags: passive-voice, intransitive-verbs, transitive-verbs

I was taught that only transitive verbs can have passive form. But today, I met a person saying that intransitive verbs can also have passive form.

He gave 2 examples as follows.

> A1: I speak to John.
>
> P1: John is spoken to by me.
>
> A2: I look after this baby.
>
> P2: This baby is looked after by me.

Is it correct that only transitive verbs can have passive form?

Comment: Since those all have objects, they are not intransitive.

Comment: There are also 'prepositional passives' where the subject of the passive corresponds to an object of a preposition rather than of a verb. Your examples are okay, though the first one is not at all natural. A better example of a prepositional passive would be "People are looking into the matter" ~ "the matter is being looked into".

Comment: @PaulM A large hole in the road has just appeared in Oxford Street. Police are looking into it.

Comment: @PaulM, but we call these "prepositional passives" only because we assume that only transitives can be made passive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clear, prototype cases of Passive are all transitive verbs.

- *The ball was kicked out of bounds by Harry.* <= *Harry kicked the ball out of bounds.*
- *She has been interviewed before*. <= *Someone has interviewed her before*.

A lot of intransitive verbs can become effectively transitive with the addition of a preposition, like *see/look at* or *hear/listen to*:

- *Everyone heard the concert. Everyone listened to the concert.*
- *The concert was heard/listened to by everyone.*

But Passive isn't limited to these prepositional transitives; any preposition can work,
**provided** it refers to a significant effect produced in the noun phrase. Then Passive can work.
So, for instance, the first sentence below is grammatical, but the second isn't.

- *This bed was slept in by George Washington.*
- **This garden was coughed in by Harry Smith.*

Comment: But your last sentence would work with *William* and *Andrew*, no?

Comment: Perhaps in the U.K. Though coughing in a garden hardly affects the garden to a significant degree, the affect of Royal fans can reach unmeasurable heights.

Comment: Sorry, just my little -- and by *little*, I mean obscure -- joke. William and Andrew were the original Smith Brothers of cough drop fame.